# Serializing list of 2 dimensional arrays in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I'm hoping someone can help to serialize this 2d array configuration... essentially it serializies everything but doesn't serialize the 2d arrays called wallConfig0...3. Right now I have 4 of them, but I'd like to have a list of wallConfig 2d arrays that I can serialize to JSON. Please give me some guidance on how to serialize this data structure. Thanks.

-Rik

I have a list of rooms:

```
    [Serializable]
public class RoomDataList
{
    public List<RoomData> roomDataList = new List<RoomData>();
}
```

Each room has this data:

```
[Serializable]
    public class RoomData {
        public int[,] wallConfig0;//TODO: change to list of 2d arrays
        public int[,] wallConfig1;
        public int[,] wallConfig2;
        public int[,] wallConfig3;

    public float[] wallLoc0;//TODO: change to list of vector3
    public float[] wallLoc1;
    public float[] wallLoc2;
    public float[] wallLoc3;

    public float wallRot0;
    public float wallRot1;
    public float wallRot2;
    public float wallRot3;

    public int[,] floorConfig;
    public int parentRoomIndex;
    public int parentDoorIndex;
    public float parentDoorWallSize;
    public int roomIndex;
    public Vector3 location;
    public Quaternion rotation;
    public string filePath;
    public string[] folderContents0;
    public string[] folderContents1;
}
```

Here are my load/save to JSON functions:

```
private static RoomDataList LoadRoomData(string path) {
    string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
    return JsonUtility.FromJson<RoomDataList>(json);

}
private static void SaveRoomData(string path, RoomDataList roomDataList) {
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(roomDataList);

    StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path);
    sw.Close();
    File.WriteAllText(path, json);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that ended up working: essentially wrappers within wrappers:

```
[Serializable]
public class RoomDataList
{
    public List<RoomData> roomDataList = new List<RoomData>();
}

[Serializable]
public class RoomData
{

    public string guid;

    public List<WallConfig> wallConfigList = new List<WallConfig>();
    public float[] counts;

    public Vector3 wallLoc0;
    public Vector3 wallLoc1;
    public Vector3 wallLoc2;
    public Vector3 wallLoc3;

    public float wallRot0;
    public float wallRot1;
    public float wallRot2;
    public float wallRot3;

    public float[] size;

    public string[] doorRoomGuid;

    public int parentRoomIndex;
    public int parentDoorIndex;
    public float parentDoorWallSize;
    public int roomIndex;
    public Vector3 location;
    public Quaternion rotation;
    public string filePath;
    public string[] folderContents0;
    public string[] folderContents1;
}

[Serializable]
public class WallConfig {
    public List<WallFloorConfig> wallConfig=new List<WallFloorConfig>();
}

[Serializable]
public class WallFloorConfig
{
    public int[] wallFloorConfig;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You **can't** serialize array, but you **can** serialize class with list, so for serializing array you need to wrap matrix to lists, wrap this lists to class and serialize this class. For example:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Cell
{
    //some stuff
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Array
{
    public List<Cell> cells = new List<Cell>();
    public Cell this[int index] => cells[index];
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Matrix
{
    public List<Array> arrays = new List<Array>();
    public Cell this[int x, int y] => arrays[x][y];
}
```

Don't forget to use ***this*** for easy data reaching like "Matrix[0,1]"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Unity doesn't automatically serialize multi-dimensional arrays or Lists. In your case, a simple workaround is to replace the 2D arrays with an array of `Vector2`s.

Similarly, in other situations, you can replace a multi-dimensional array with a class/struct containing as many variable as you want and then create an array of this class/struct.